# How to create object and it's methods dynamically in Ruby as in Javascript?

Tags: ruby, object, methods

I recently found that dynamically creating object and methods in Ruby is quite a work, this might be because of my background experience in Javascript.

In Javascript you can dynamically create object and it's methods as follow:

```
function somewhere_inside_my_code() {
  foo = {};
  foo.bar = function() { /** do something **/ };
};
```

How is the equivalent of accomplishing the above statements in Ruby (as simple as in Javascript)?

Comment: When you program Ruby, you probably shouldn't try to port over your JS approaches. The languages have quite different object models, there will be a mismatch of paradigms.

Comment: That is correct, thanks for reminding. I simply need a small throw away object that's used only within a single action in my app, and perhaps the main reason is that I don't want to do it in a procedural way, it's rather clunky. :D

Comment: Then you should look at [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

Comment: @michael Yup, I'm considering that too, it seems quite easy to add properties as in Javascript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this with singleton methods. Note that you can do this with all objects, for example:

```
str = "I like cookies!"

def str.piratize
  self + " Arrrr!"
end

puts str.piratize
```

which will output:

```
I like cookies! Arrrr!
```

These methods are really only defined on this single object (hence the name), so this code (executed after the above code):

```
str2 = "Cookies are great!"
puts str2.piratize
```

just throws an exception:

```
undefined method `piratize' for "Cookies are great!":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Great answer. I've seen it before, but somehow it doesn't even cross my mind, hahaha. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like that:

```
foo = Object.new

def foo.bar
  1+1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `OpenStruct`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html, it resembles JavaScript in some way, but only with properties, not methods. Ruby and JavaScript use too different ideas for objects.